# Change date contribution or membership offers date of day but 10 years ago

Tags: joomla, contributions, dates

We are facing a very strange problem. At the time of resuming a contribution or changing an end date, today we cannot choose a date beyond 2014. Automatically the date of the day fills the 3 fields but 10 years back ?!?
However, when I click to renew membership, I do not encounter this problem (if only the date of accession is not up to date, neither will the date of automatic end of accession be correct).
Then, when I resume membership, the date field offers me again the date of the day 10 years ago ?!?

[image: today date but 10 years ago]

Does anyone encounter this problem? What can we do to solve it?

CiviCRM 5.57.3 | Joomla! 4.4.3

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug for PH* strict rule

This was [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27228) in Civi version 5.66. You can either apply the [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27228.patch) or upgrade Civi to the latest.